# auto complete / closing tags inside backtick, typescript, visual studio code

Tags: autocomplete, typescript, tags, visual-studio-code

Inside an HTML comment (HTML file) `<!-- -->` VS Code auto completes / closes tags, for example:

`<!-- h1 -->` - <kbd>TAB</kbd>, results in `<!-- <h1></h1> -->`

I was wondering whether it is possible enable this feature inside `backticks` or `single quotes`, within typescript files? Suggestions (IntelliSense) are shown when typing, but not completed when tab is pressed.

`` template : `h1` `` - <kbd>TAB</kbd>, results in `` template : `h1` `` and *not* `` template : `<h1></h1>` ``

Comment: As far as TypeScript is concerned, anything inside backticks, single, or double quotes is just a string. How would it know that you're typing html inside of the string? You can use a templateUrl instead of the template string. Then you'd get the auto-completion inside of the html file.

Comment: Then how would it know you're typing HTML inside a `<!-- -->`, the thought was that if it would be possible inside a comment section, why not within `strings / backticks`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I use an extension for VSC, that does just that. "Angular 2 typescript emmet"

Answer (score -1):

In VS Code editor, I use [**Angular 4 and Typescript HTML**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danwahlin.angular2-snippets) extension:

[image: Angular 4 and TypeScript/HTML VS Code Snippets]